# Ratio scale explanatory variables in ordinal regression

Tags: ordered-logit

I have a dependent variable which is ordinal, so based on logistic distribution. I need to run ordinal regression, but I have ratio scale independent variables as well as categorical: so how can I run this technique? Is it suitable? If yes, then, in which software?

Comment: I see no connection between having an ordinal response and a logistic distribution (which is a continuous univariate distribution).

Comment: To expand on Nick's comment you need to use the correct terminology.  A logistic distribution applies to a continuous $Y$.  The family of logistic regression _models_ pertains to binary, polytomous, or ordinal $Y$.  Continuous $Y$ is also ordinal so you can use an ordinal model (logistic or otherwise) on continuous $Y$.

Comment: If the response is ordinal, that's one thing, but why would it matter whether the IVs were continuous or ordered categorical, nominal or whatever?

Answer (score 3):

This is a standard situation, fully allowed for by standard ordinal response models such as the proportional odds, proportional hazards, and probit ordinal models.  The linearity assumption is key.  Standard software handles the situation you describe.